# Eclipse Javascript code assist problem in using WTP

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm new to WTP so excuse me if the solution to this is obvious. When i define and use a class from within the same file i get nice code assist help, i also get code assist for classes from the standard libraries. Unortunatly, when i try to use code and declarations from one file in another file i no longer get t he nice code assist features. I have searched the web and tried a couple of things, making shoure JS is enabled for the project, making sure the folder the scripts are in is added to the JS source folder list and even trying making a new folder with the decleration files in and adding it as a library. I would really like ot get this feature working so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works for me.  (don'cha hate that?)  What version of eclipse are you using?  OS?  JRE?

Answer (score 0):

you can try [spket IDE](http://spket.com/). after install, you need to config javascript profile to get code assist works for you.